# gnome style bottom panel on kde

Tags: centos, kde, desktop-environment, gnome-panel

I like the bottom panel on CentOS6/gnome, where the buttons corresponding to the running applications make it easy to quickly bring forward the application you want to work on, and workplace switcher is also very useful.

Now I've got CentOS7/kde-plasma desktop and miss the bottom panel, mostly because switching foreground application with Alt-Tab is much less convenient than by just clicking on the one you want.

How can I customize kde-plasma to have the gnome-style bottom panel?